# Google Apps Script : Track Change

Tags: google-apps-script

Good day

What would be the correct way to track changes on a website?

using  "`UrlFetchApp.fetch("http://www.example.com/");`"

```
<p class='pagination-results-count'><span>Results 1 to 4</span>
    </p>
```

I would like to track any changes to "Results 1 to 4"

Cheers

Trenton

Answer (score 0):

Once you have fetched the page content with UrlFetch, you can extract the <p> tag with the pagination attribute using regex and store the value in a spreadsheet or in the script cache.

Set up a trigger that repeats the step every, say, 5 minutes and if the old value is different from the new one, it sends out an email to you.